# How to verify that a shuffling algorithm is uniform?

Tags: python, algorithm, shuffle

I have a simple Python implementation of [Knuth's shuffling algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle):

```
def knuth_shuffle(ar):
    num = len(ar)
    for i in range(num):
        index = random.randint(0, i)
        ar[i], ar[index] = ar[index], ar[i]
    return ar
```

How is it possible to test (using `scipy` or whatever other package) that the shuffling is indeed uniform? I have found a couple of related posts ([1](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/147134/how-should-i-test-randomness), [2](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/47338/whats-a-uniform-shuffle/47342)) but they don't answer my question. It would be great to understand how to perform such checks in general.

Comment: In what way did [1](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/147134/how-should-i-test-randomness) not answer your question?

Comment: Knuth proved uniformity of the shuffle. This is done by showing that it is the same as picking N items out of a set of N items without replacement. Which is the same as generating a series of random numbers from decreasing ranges which then forms the factorial base index of the permutation.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2435/is-there-a-simple-test-for-uniform-distributions is relevant. For small vectors, there are few enough possible permutations that you can just count each distinct shuffled result. For larger vectors, spot check some subsets (eg elements <7, 12 and 15>.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*EDIT:*

As [Paul Hankin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1400793) in the comments, my original test only checked that the probability of each element falling into each position, but not that all permutations are equally likely, which is a stronger requirement. The snippet below counts the frequency of each permutation, which is what we should be looking at:

```
import math
import random

def knuth_shuffle(ar):
    num = len(ar)
    for i in range(num):
        index = random.randint(0, i)
        ar[i], ar[index] = ar[index], ar[i]
    return ar

# This function computes a unique index for a given permutation
# Adapted from https://www.jaapsch.net/puzzles/compindx.htm#perm
def permutation_index(permutation):
    n = len(permutation)
    t = 0
    for i in range(n):
      t = t * (n - i)
      for j in range(i + 1, n):
        if permutation[i] > permutation[j]:
            t += 1
    return t

N = 6  # Test list size
T = 1000  # Trials / number of permutations

random.seed(100)
n_perm = math.factorial(N)
trials = T * n_perm
ar = list(range(N))
freq = [0] * n_perm
for _ in range(trials):
    ar_shuffle = ar.copy()
    knuth_shuffle(ar_shuffle)
    freq[permutation_index(ar_shuffle)] += 1
```

If the shuffle is uniform, the values of the resulting `freq` vector should be distributed according to a binomial distribution with `T * N!` trials and probability of success `1 / (N!)`. Here is a plot of a distribution estimation for the previous example (done with [Seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/)), where frequency values should be around 1000:

[image: Permutation frequency distribution]

Which I think looks *good* but again, for a quantitative result you would need a deeper statistical analysis, such as [Pearson's chi-squared test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test), as suggested by [David Eisenstat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2144669).

---

*ORIGINAL ANSWER:*

I'm going to put here some basic ideas, but I don't have the strongest background on statistics so someone may want to complement or correct anything that is wrong.

You can make a matrix of frequencies of each value falling into each position for a number of trials:

```
def knuth_shuffle(ar):
    num = len(ar)
    for i in range(num):
        index = random.randint(0, i)
        ar[i], ar[index] = ar[index], ar[i]
    return ar

N = 100  # Test list size
T = 10000  # Number of trials
ar = list(range(N))
freq = [[0] * N for _ in range(N)]

for _ in range(T):
    ar_shuffle = ar.copy()
    kunth_shuffle(ar_shuffle)
    for i, j in enumerate(ar_shuffle):
        freq[i][j] += 1
```

Once you can do that, there are several approaches you can take. A simple idea is, if the shuffle is uniform, `freq / T` should tend to `1 / N` as `T` tends to infinity. So you can just use a "very big" value of `T` and see that those values are "close enough". Or check that the standard deviation of `freq / T - 1 / N` is "small enough".

These "close enough" and "small enough" though are not very solid concepts. The grounded analysis requires more statistical tools. I think you would need to [test the hipothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing) that each frequency value is sampled from a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with `T` trials a `1 / N` success probability. As I said do not have the background for a full explanation of that and this is probably not the place for it but if you really need a thorough analysis you can read up on the topic.

Comment: You want a chi^2 test: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test

Comment: If you implement shuffle as `r=random.randint(len(ar)); ar = ar[r:] + ar[:r]` (that is, pick a random cyclic permutation of the input), you'll pass this test. That's maybe an artificial example, but there are huge classes of statistical errors in the results that aren't caught by only checking how often each item goes into which slot.

Comment: @PaulHankin I see, you are right, thanks. I changed the code to actually test the frequency of each possible permutation.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Thank you, yes, I think that is the kind of thing I was thinking of, but I am too rusty on that too remember properly.

Answer (score 3):

You can check this exactly, by injecting all possible sequences of random numbers into `knuth_shuffle`, and then verifying you get each permutation exactly once.

This code does that:

```
import collections
import itertools
import random

def knuth_shuffle(ar, R=random.randint):
    num = len(ar)
    for i in range(num):
        index = R(0, i)
        ar[i], ar[index] = ar[index], ar[i]
    return ar

def fact(i):
    r = 1
    while i > 1:
        r *= i
        i -= 1
    return r

def all_random_seqs(N):
    for r in range(fact(N)):
        seq = []
        for i in range(N):
            seq.append(r % (i+1))
            r //= (i+1)
        it = iter(seq)
        yield lambda x, y: next(it)

for N in range(1, 6):
    print N
    results = collections.Counter()
    for R in all_random_seqs(N):
        a = list('ABCDEFG'[:N])
        knuth_shuffle(a, R)
        results[''.join(a)] += 1
    print 'checking...'
    if len(results) != fact(N):
        print 'N=%d. Not enough results. %s' % (N, results)
    if any(c > 1 for c in results.itervalues()):
        print 'N=%d. Not all permutations unique. %s' % (N, results)
    if any(sorted(c) != list('ABCDEFG'[:N]) for c in results.iterkeys()):
        print 'N=%d. Some permutations are illegal. %s' % (N, results)
```

This code checks exact correctness for input lists of size 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. You can probably go a little further before N! gets too large.

You will also want to perform sanity checks on the version of the code using `random.randint` (for example generating 500 shuffles of 'ABCD', and making sure you get each permutation at least once).

Answer (score 0):

If you randomly shuffle the same items from a given fixed order, then the count of each item in *one* fixed position in the shuffled items should tend to the same value.

Below I shuffle the list 0..9 a few times and print the output:

```
from random import shuffle  # Uses Fischer-Yates

tries = 1_000_000
intcount = 10
first_position_counts = {n:0 for n in ints}
ints = range(intcount)
for _ in range(tries):
    lst = list(ints)   # [0, 1, ...9] In that order
    shuffle(lst)
    first_position_counts[lst[0]] += 1

print(f'{tries} shuffles of the ints 0..{intcount-1} should have each int \n',
      'appear in the first position {tries/intcount} times.')
for item in first_position_counts.items():
    print(' %i: %5i' % item)
```

Run once you might get something like:

```
 0: 99947
 1: 100522
 2: 99828
 3: 100123
 4: 99582
 5: 99635
 6: 99991
 7: 100108
 8: 100172
 9: 100092
```

And again:

```
 0: 100049
 1: 99918
 2: 100053
 3: 100285
 4: 100293
 5: 100034
 6: 99861
 7: 99584
 8: 100055
 9: 99868
```

Now if you have thousands of items to shuffle, then they should end up in one of `n!` permutations, **but `n!` grows large, quckly**; and if it is "comparable", certainly grater than the possible range of your random number generator then it breaks down.

Comment: The fact that individual positions are uniform does not say much about the uniformity of the permutation. Suppose the shuffle *only* produced rotations, but it produced uniformly distributed rotations. Then each position will also be uniformly distributed, but the shuffle algorithm is clearly inadequate.

Comment: What makes you think that the shuffle produces  rotations? That is highly unlikely - go look at the algorithm yourself. If you still think that rotations are the most likely outcome then devise a test for rotations. I don't think that it is necessary. (Plus see Dan D's suggestion of a proof, above).

Comment: Correctly implemented, of course, the shuffle algorithm works perfectly (depending on the quality of the random number generator). But if we just believed that, there would be no point testing at all. The rotation example is extreme, but it demonstrates that there is more to testing the uniformity of random shuffle than just uniformity of each position. You also need to test that the elements in each permutation are uncorrelated with each other. (And a bad random number generator could induce such a correlation.)

Comment: "You also need to test that ...": There is usually someone with different needs than oneself. A0onther test for hidden patterns might be to assign each item in the starting list a colour and plot colours for successive generated permutations. I am not saying other tests can't be devised, Just that you might want to "pluck the low hangng fruit first" and one will have to stop at some stage, knowing that someone could devise yet another test...